# Cannot read config.json correctly (TypeScript, Webpack)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-universal

**UPDATE**: the issue is fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/commit/4e8a5e30ef0a7629b12025b5ccb9a9b22ffe5bbc)

---

> Be ware of that the reason that the problem comes out and normal pure JavaScript ways cannot solve it could be because that **server.ts** is using **TypeScript** and **Webpack**. Check Gant's answer. And track [this issue](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/149) on github.

I am using [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as starter. I have a file **config.json**

```
{
  "api": "123"
}
```

When I read `config` in **server.ts**:

```
import * as config from '../config.json';
// const config = require('../config.json');  will be same result
console.log(config);
```

It shows this in the terminal:

```
{
  "api": "123"
}
```

However, when I try to read `config.api` in **server.ts**:

```
import * as config from '../config.json';
// const config = require('../config.json');  will be same result
console.log(config.api);
```

It shows `undefined`.

This is my folder structure (other part same like [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)).

```
my-app
  - config.json
  + src
    - server.ts
```

And when I launch the app, I use `npm start`.

What may cause this? Thanks

Comment: `import config from './config.json';`. If its in node, you can just require it. const config = require('./config.json').

Comment: @SwarajGiri then both `console.log(config);` and `console.log(config.api);` will show `undefined `

Comment: I don't see any files named `config.json` in that repository.

Comment: @SeeDart i use it as starter, `config.json` is my own file.

Comment: Are you using a relative or absolute path? Can you share what your file structure looks like?

Comment: @SeeDart relative path

Comment: If you're using node, can you check to see if [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) can read the file?

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to answer this. As it stands, your work should execute. Please add a details section with 1) the relative project path of `config.json` 2) the file in which you write your js code (or REPL) and 3) the command you use to start the project..

Comment: @amingilani just added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration file is inlined by webpack, so it follows the ES6 module spec and returns the JSON as a string and not an object as you'd expect from Node.

Is there a reason you build the server with webpack in the first place?

Comment: Hmm, no specific reason, just because official angular/universal-starter uses it, so I just use it directly to quick start

Comment: thanks! I also aware of that `console.log(config);` returns a string instead of a json actually! That is why I tried `JSON.parse` and then it works

Comment: @HongboMiao it's a really weird thing to do. It breaks some assumptions you can make about running under node and adds compile time for something that doesn't need to be bundled (just compiled). I'll see if I can get an issue up later.

Comment: that is a point! maybe you can help create an issue on https://github.com/angular/universal-starter to avoid people meet problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: the issue is fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/commit/4e8a5e30ef0a7629b12025b5ccb9a9b22ffe5bbc)

---

> Be ware of that the reason that the problem comes out and normal pure JavaScript ways cannot solve it could be because that **server.ts** is using **TypeScript** and **Webpack**. Check Gant's answer. And track [this issue](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/149) on github.

I found the problem:

```
import * as config from '../config.json';
// const config = require('../config.json'); also works


const json = JSON.parse(config);  // <- need this line
console.log(json.api);  // 123
```

Comment: I'd considered that but that shouldn't have been true in JS. Maybe it's Typescript thing. Please add the Typescript tag to your question. And make the title more descriptive, e.g. "Cannot parse JSON file in TypeScript" to avoid more downvotes.

Comment: @amingilani oh, you got it, I think that is why this problem happens!

Comment: @amingilani see my response, the boilerplate uses webpack to compile the server and the module loader for typescript automatically inlines the JSON, so you get the ES6 behavior. The node require is never actually used.

Comment: @HongboMiao require works, but need to use string index. you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Method 1 is wrong as it does not match the question configuration. The webpack configuration in question use raw-loader for json file, while this answer is using json-loader.

Use the method 2

Both methods tested with nodejs + webpack.

**Method 1**

```
var config = require(__dirname + '/config.json');
console.log(config['api']);
```

**Method 2**

```
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(config.api);
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work because the boilerplate uses `loader-raw` for JSON files.

Comment: @Gant You are right, I didn't clone to the repo and was using my own webpack config which use json-loader. My bad.